# Insecure forms and proxy servers?

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, tomcat, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a web application written in Apache Tomcat 8.5 that is proxied behind NGINX. i.e. I am using NGINX to offload SSL and serve static images etc. The app has been working reliably for years.

Now, the Chrome 87 update is causing a warning "The information that you’re about to submit is not secure" on every form submission. I've gone through the code with a fine-toothed comb and I can't figure out what could be triggering it.

The user gets to NGINX on https and the certificate is valid. NGINX forwards the request to Tomcat on port 8080. See config below.

The forms are submitted on the tomcat server as HTTP. But NGINX should prevent the browser from knowing that. It's https as far as the browser knows...

All  tags are written as relative links or implied to be the same URL. e.g.
`<form action="/login/login.do" method="post">` or `<form method="post">`.

Can anyone please point out something to look for? Am I missing a header or something?

Thanks in advance

from NGINX conf.d/site.conf:

```
location ~ \.(do|jsp)$ {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
```

Comment: Same issue here with a symfony app running behind Traefik as a reverse proxy. Have tried putting `X-Forwarded-Proto https` and `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` in nginx config, none worked...still trying to figure out a solution

Comment: Look at the HTML generated by your web application. Are all the links and `<form action=` using `https` or are they using `http`? If so, then you have misconfigured Tomcat and should look at your `<Connector>` settings, in particular the `scheme`, `secure`, and `proxyPort` attributes. You should also ensure you are using the `RemoteIPValve` to pick-up the proxy's incoming HTTP headers for things like logging.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a [change in Chrome 87](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/08/protecting-google-chrome-users-from.html) to give warnings for mixed forms, so that is probably why those errors are appearing.

Perhaps there are some stray absolute links within your application which are still http, and are not being automatically converted when proxied by nginx?

If you are sure all your content is served over https, you can try enabling this header `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` ([more info here](https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/#upgrading-insecure-requests)) to force browsers to upgrade insecure connections automatically.

Comment: I've tried with this solution and with this one https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2013/04/09/making-ssl-work-with-django-behind but they don't seem to fix the issue. It looks like redirects after login are being considered as insecure, but I still don't know why if they are using https.

Comment: I've also tried with instructions in Django docs and it didn't work either: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/security/#ssl-https

Comment: I think http redirects are counted as insecure, and I noticed this problem as well with my PHP app. I had to "trick" PHP into returning https URLs with `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` Would it be possible to add a middleware that translates your http redirects to https? https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/02/how-to-make-django-redirect-www-to-your-bare-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, and in my case was the response from my app server being a redirect to a different scheme (http) than the one used by the client (https).

If it's your case as well, adding this to your `location` definition should do the trick. Assuming your app/app server respects this header, then it should respond with the proper scheme (https) on the `Location` header.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

For completeness, excerpt for [X-Forwarded-Proto from MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto):

> The X-Forwarded-Proto (XFP) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) that a client used to connect to your proxy or load balancer.